# \tau symbol like a real number \Re

Tags: symbols, amsmath

How can I get `\tau` to be like the real number symbol `\Re` similar to the ones in the attached photo.

[image: symbols]

Comment: Why is this tagged as `latex3`?

Comment: Sorry, a mistake.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have removed that tag (and formatted a bit). OOzyPal Do you mean this blackboard math font?

Comment: @TeXnician: I could have removed the tag also, but I wanted to 'annoy' the O.P. ;-)

Comment: Your Title is very confusing as you show blackboard bold  (double struck) R  but you ask for a style like `\Re` which makes a script R not at all like the image that you show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very ugly version with `\bbtau` from package `mathbbol` and its `bbgreekl` option. Don't use it  ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}


\begin{document}

$\bbtau$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: interestingly enough Unicode only has the math double struck in latin and arabic, not greek.....  So if this was used in publication once could apply to extend Unicode...

Comment: As you said it is ugly :). Also it does not scale well with the other equations. I will just go with \mathbb{T}.

Comment: @OOzyPal: Well, you asked for `\tau` in black board letters. `\mathbb{T}` is black board T ;-)